# How can I take a backingbean GSON string to Highcharts

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces, highcharts, gson

I'm fairly new when it comes to JS, jQuery and JSON stuff, so any help is greatly appreciated. I have a project I am trying to work with Highcharts on, that's JSF 2.2, RichFaces 4. I've already got my backing bean which pulls data from a database, and put's store's in a collection. I then convert the collection to a GSON string. A sample of the data, from a printout of the GSON object is

> {"Pool Price":[{"date":"Date.UTC(2012,5,4,1)","data":"1144.144"},{"date":"Date.UTC(2012,5,4,2)","data":"1030.421"}],
>       "RAPP":[{"date":"Date.UTC(2012,5,4,1)","data":"11.50"},{"date":"Date.UTC(2012,5,4,2)","data":"10.87"}]}

When it comes to the page, I designed a chart in JSFiddle from the HighCharts example page, and used some hard-coded values to get the look/design right.

My problem now, is getting the data from the backing bean, to highcharts. My page right now looks like this

```
<h:head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function chartdata() {

           console.log("Grabbing chart data");
           var data = jQuery("#chartvalue").attr('value');

             }
         });
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false" >

<a4j:commandButton value="LoadData" oncomplete="chartdata();" action="#{dailyReportBean.loadChartData}" id="chartvalue_btn" />
<h:inputHidden value="#{dailyReportBean.json}" id="chartvalue"  />

        <div id="container">
            <script src="DR_PoolPrice_Graph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

A preset JS file with the values coded in, loads fine. So the problem is just acessing the data from in chartdata() to the highcharts file, and how i reference that.

Here's what the highcharts file looks like

```
$(function() {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#FFFFCC','#799ECD',]
});

var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        backgroundColor: '#FCD5B5',
        borderColor: 'EBBA95',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 10,
        spacingLeft: 40,
        spacingRight: 20,
        zoomType: 'x',
        plotBorderColor: '#346691',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        plotBackgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 0,
                y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
                ]
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Price'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },

    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            x: -25
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        floating: false,
        align: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        layout: 'horizontal',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 0,
        shadow: true
    },

    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            align: 'right'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RAPP',
        data: rapp,
        type: 'area'},
        {
        name: 'Pool Price',
        data: poolprice},
    ]
});
});
```

I am sorry that this is a rather large post, I just wanted to be thorough, as I've tried looking at this a bunch of different ways and it's just not clicking for me. I am sure it's something silly.

Thanks for any input you can provide!

Comment: What is a GSON string? Isn't GSON a java library that creates JSON strings? Also, you have several(2) extra commas, IE will choke on them.

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes GSON is a java library that creates JSON strings. Since we're using Java/JSF it seemed to make sense to use the GSON library to generate the JSON string. Sorry for not being clear about that. I'll have to start cleaning up the commas before pushing this live, but would rather get something functioning so I can clean it up after :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with highcharts, but how were you passing data to it originally? It shouldn't be any different. It looks like you were using a `poolprice` variable.

Comment: poolprice is what is in the GSON string as a series, when I used hard-coded values it would have looked like data: ["date":"Date.UTC(2012,5,4,1)","data":"1144.144"]

Comment: It doesn't look like you are executing `chartdata` anywhere, and if it is meant to be executed within another js file, it would need to be on the global scope (no `$(document).ready()`) and before the script that uses it.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I got that part figured out to pull the data to where highcharts can see the variable. Now I just need to figure out how to assign each series in the JSON string to a chart series. I've renamed the jQuery JSON string to cdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*Ajax call to get the Chart data in JSON Format */
function getJsonChartData(str ) 
           {

    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.open("GET", "drawChart.php?client_name="+str, true);

    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var done = 4, ok = 200;
        if(http_request.readyState == done && http_request.status == ok) {
            my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);  // JS json Object to capture the returning json text 
                chart.showLoading(); // show loading image on chart

            /***************** setting data to chart dynamically *************/


            chart.series[1].setData(my_JSON_object[5]); //should be 5

            chart.series[2].setData(my_JSON_object[4]);

            chart.series[3].setData(my_JSON_object[1]);

            chart.series[4].setData(my_JSON_object[0]);

            chart.series[5].setData(my_JSON_object[2]);

                chart.series[6].setData(my_JSON_object[3]);

            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(my_JSON_object[6]); 



        }
    };
    http_request.send(null);

}
```

I went through with your question , but didn't got what you really wanted , any way if you trying to load highchart data dynamically from a JS file best way is to do a ajax call and get the data as a JSON object , then set that data manually by referring highchart's chart object above example is what how I used it to set data , via a php file , hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, this got me what I needed! Sorry for the terrible explanation! Thanks to Kevin B for the help earlier on the pushing as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `<h:inputHidden>` on the ajax request so that jQuery gets the updated value.

```
<a4j:commandButton ... render="chartvalue" />
```

Easier is to just pass it as an argument into `oncomplete`:

```
<a4j:commandButton ... oncomplete="chartdata(#{dailyReportBean.json})" />
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chartdata(data) {
        console.log("Chart data already retrieved: " + data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know what's the issue with mine I need single quote in #{dailyReportBean.json >> '#{dailyReportBean.json}'

Comment: @Kitex: you'd need it if it's not in JSON format, but a plain vanilla string in a different format such as HTML. The answer assumes JSON, so singlequotes are not needed.