# JSF El expression retaining old value (JSF life cycle)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, page-lifecycle

I have create a test project with JSF2.0 and richfaces. I am trying to plot chart. Now, I got value from database to bean and to datatable. Now when I wanted to pass this value to javascript varible and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023633/591559) from The BalusC very userful. It works fine but the value that javascript variable gets after oncomplete="jsonDemo('#{kpilist.json}')". i.e. the value of #{kpilist.json} is not up-to-date it's last one.

I have printed the value of  #{kpilist.json}. If it's printed afer datatabe the value is current. If it's printed before datatable it's last value. Any way since oncomplete attribute of a4j:ajax executes after eveything is completed why doesn't #{kpilist.json} show latest value?  What is the order of execution of various listener and oncomplete attributes of richfaces and jsf component?

My Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "kpilist")
@ViewScoped
public class KPIListController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean state = true;
    String selectedKPIType;
    String selectKPITime = "D";
    boolean renderDatatable;
    String json;



    public String getJson() {
        return json;       
    }


    public boolean isRenderDatatable() {
        return renderDatatable;
    }

    public void setRenderDatatable(boolean renderDatatable) {
        this.renderDatatable = renderDatatable;
    }

    public boolean isState() {
        return state;
    }

    public List<String> showViewList() {
        Logger.getLogger(KPIListController.class.getName()).warning("Show view List:");
        KPIDAO kpiDAO = new KPIDAO();
        try {
            Logger.getLogger(KPIListController.class.getName()).info("Into show view List ---select One");
            return kpiDAO.showViewList(selectKPITime);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(KPIListController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getSelectedKPIType() {
        return selectedKPIType;
    }

    public void setSelectedKPIType(String selectedKPIType) {
        this.selectedKPIType = selectedKPIType;
    }

    public String getSelectKPITime() {
        return selectKPITime;
    }

    public void setSelectKPITime(String selectKPITime) {
        this.selectKPITime = selectKPITime;
    }

    public List<KPI> getKPI() {
        Logger.getLogger(KPIListController.class.getName()).warning("Get KPI Values:");
        KPIDAO kpiDAO = new KPIDAO();        
         List<KPI> kpiList = new ArrayList<KPI>();

        try {
            kpiList = kpiDAO.getKPI(selectedKPIType);  
            Logger.getLogger(KPIListController.class.getName()).warning("KPI List:"+kpiList.size());            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
         Gson gson = new Gson();
        json= gson.toJson(kpiList);
        return kpiList;
    }

    public void resetFormValues() {       
        Logger.getLogger(KPIListController.class.getName()).warning("Reset form:");
        selectedKPIType = "--";
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/contentTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="windowTitle">KPI Index</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content" >

                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/jquery.js"/>   
                <h:outputStylesheet name="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css"/>
                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"/>
                <h:outputScript name="js/OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js"/>

                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/raphael-min.js"/>
                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/canvg.js"/>
                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/paths.js"/> 
                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/draw.js"/> 

                <h:form id="ins_sel_form">
                    <h:outputText value="KPI TIME FRAME"/>
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{kpilist.selectKPITime}"  >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="DAILY" itemValue="D"   />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="WEEKLY" itemValue="W"  />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="LAST WEEK" itemValue="LW"  />    
                        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="ins_sel_form:selectOnemenu dataPnl"  listener="#{kpilist.resetFormValues()}" /> 
                    </h:selectOneRadio>

                    <h:outputText value="Major KPI Type"/>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOnemenu" value="#{kpilist.selectedKPIType}"  >
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="--" itemLabel="--"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItems itemValue="#{item.toString()}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.toString()}" value="#{kpilist.showViewList()}"/>
                        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="dataPnl"  oncomplete="jsonDemo('#{kpilist.json}')" /> 
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Show / Hide Map"/>

                </h:form>
                <rich:panel  id ="dataPnl">

                        <rich:dataTable id="kpiValueTable" value="#{kpilist.KPI}" var="kpi" style="width:100%" rows="20" rendered="#{kpilist.selectedKPIType!=null and kpilist.selectedKPIType !='--' }" >                            

                            <rich:column>
                                <f:facet name="header" >
                                    <h:outputText value ="Value"></h:outputText>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{kpi.KPIValue}"></h:outputText>
                            </rich:column>

                        </rich:dataTable>
                    JSON String :  <h:outputText  id="json" value ="#{kpilist.json}"/>   
                        <center><rich:dataScroller for="kpiValueTable" rendered="#{kpilist.selectedKPIType!=null and kpilist.selectedKPIType!='--'}"/></center>
                    </rich:panel>

                <rich:panel id="map" style="display: none;">
                </rich:panel>


            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function jsonDemo(jsonString){

    console.log("Chart data already retrieved: " + jsonString);
    var data = $.parseJSON(jsonString);    
    $.each(data,function(i,val){
         console.log("The value of i: "+i+" The val: "+val.NCELLCLUSTER);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EL expression in your `oncomplete` is evaluated at the moment the HTML/JS code is generated by JSF (thus, on the initial HTTP request). It's not evaluated at the moment the `oncomplete` is executed in JS as you seem to expect. It's not the webbrowser who evaluates EL expressions, it's the webserver. The `oncomplete` is by the way just executed after `render`. With a HTTP traffic debugger and a JS debugger (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug) you can easily track it.

There are several possibilities to solve this:

1. Just invoke a `$.get()` or `$.getJSON()` in jQuery and do the job in a [normal servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/4113258#4113258) instead, or better, a JAX-RS webservice.

   ```
   function jsonDemo() {
       $.getJSON("servletURL", function(jsonData) {
           // ...
       });
   }
   ```
2. Replace the `oncomplete` by some `<h:outputScript>` which you render/update by ajax.

   ```
   <a4j:ajax ... render="json" />
   ...
   <h:panelGroup id="json">
       <h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty bean.json}">jsonDemo(#{bean.json});</h:outputScript>
   </h:panelGroup>
   ```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've there by the way a conceptual mistake as to passing around JSON data. You're stringifying it while passing as argument like so `jsonDemo('#{kpilist.json}')` and then you're parsing the JSON afterwards using `$.parseJSON()`. This makes no sense. Remove those singlequotes around the argument like so `jsonDemo(#{kpilist.json})` and then you don't need that `$.parseJSON()` line anymore. The data is then *already* in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from `a4j:ajax` to `f:ajax`

not sure if `a4j:ajax` works with plain JSF components

Comment: yes it works hmmm .. but don't know the order of execution of it's component like oncomplete, render etc..

Comment: take a look at this example of BalucS , pay attention to `onevent="showProgress"` to the `showProgress` implementation , http://stackoverflow.com/a/7044332/617373